# Cypress network request with dynamic body

Tags: json, python-requests, request, cypress

I would like to create cypress custom method which will be using parameter as a dynamic request body (to avoid code duplicate because url, method and headers are always the same) like that:

```js
var bodyValue = 
`abc
 abc
 abc`

 var bodyValue2 = 
`bbb
 bbb
 bbb`

Cypress.Commands.add("myRequest", () => {


  cy.request({

    url: "xxx",
    method: 'PUT',

    headers: {
      authorization: cookies
    },

    body: bodyValue

    
  })
```

})

it always ends with

```
The response we got was:
```

```js
Status: 409 - Conflict
Headers: {
  xxx
  xxx
  xxx
}
Body: {
  "message": "Setting Deleted"
}
```

Whats funny if I take value from my variable and just paste it into body:

```js
cy.request({

    url: "xxx",
    method: 'PUT',

    headers: {
      authorization: cookies
    },

    body: {
     abc
     abc
     abc
}
```

})

It is always working

I also have tried

cy.request({

```
    url: "xxx",
    method: 'PUT',

    headers: {
      authorization: cookies
    },

    body: {bodyValue}
```

})

It is weird because because body after that is not

```
     abc
     abc
     abc
```

but

```
{"bodyValue":
   abc
   abc
   abc
}
```

which may be the cause. I don't know how to achieve my goal.

My acutal bodyValue:

```js
{
    "revision": "23554252352542343",
          "activePerspective": ".Beta",
          "perspectives": [
            {
              "type": ".Beta",
              "activeLayout": "1x1",
              "layouts": [
                {
                  "caption": "1x1",
                  "canonicalName": "1x1",
                  "icon": {
                    "source": "<svg xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\" width=\"18\" height=\"18\"><path fill=\"none\" stroke=\"#fff\" class=\"eveInteractiveSvgStroke\"/></svg>"
                  },
                  "placement": {
                    "center": {
                      "config_mode": ".Default",
                      "visualization": "object-table",
                      "configuration": "punkt"
                    }
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          ]  
       }
```

Comment: Just tried cy.request PUT your actual body but without headers (as exact form unknown) -no problem, status 200.

Comment: @user16695029 did you do it using a variable?

Comment: Yes, but still checking the response to see if anything changed. Of course response is coming from different server. But it's worth checking your headers based on this test.

Comment: I dont know if you have seen my comment below but the only difference beetwen my variable and what is actually sent is missing is backslash before "  and I dont know how to prevent it I even tried using \\" or \\\" it always disapears

Comment: I am confused right now. I was using cy.log() to print what is sent but that might be wrong, i need to find out how to do it correctly. I have just learned that to escape \ in cypress you need to write \\\\ like in jquery

Comment: Right now I think it might be caused because variable is undefined at time cypress send cy.request? I am trying now to prevent that but I cant make it work

Comment: Not sure that's possible (looking at first code block). The custom command gets bodyValue by closure (because it's declared above). Are you clearing it down anywhere?

Comment: No the only thing I am doing with variable is declaring and using in cy.request. I can't explain why it didnt work but fortunately, this problem has already been resolved. As I wrote below "my co-worker said it can be caused because cypress may be trying to parse bodyValue to json even though it is already json".

Comment: Maybe, but if so I'd expect your working solution to also fail (looks like it's giving the request a JSON object).

Comment: BTW `'Content-Type': 'application/json'` since the default content type is text (which kind of supports co-workers' theory).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Fody this is not much different than your answer.

```
var body = {abc, abc, abc}
```

and inside cy.request

```
  url: "xxx",
method: 'PUT',

headers: {
  authorization: cookies
},

body
```

And it worked.

Comment: Cool, must have been bodyValue getting reset.

Comment: BTW looking up the `409` error, it says that "conflict" is because something else is trying to PUT to the same item on the server. Did you restart the server by chance?

Comment: @Fody I didn't. I am not only one working there but I dont think this has happened. My co-worker said it can be caused because cypress may be trying to parse bodyValue to json even though it is already json.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to set bodyValue as an object (before passing in)

```js
const bodyValue = { abc, abc, abc }
```

then in the request, as per first attempt

```js
body: bodyValue
```

It's hard to tell because even the working "pasted in" example has syntax errors - there should be commas between each property.

Comment: I shouldn't have written this question so fast ... The thing is I already tried it. My body value is very long json and contain many special chars, I tried puting its value inside backquotes `  `, String.raw nothing seems to be working. Whats weird when I send the same request with postman it worked perfectly. I have updated question with my acutal body.

Comment: What I found is that "\" seems to be not saved inside variable so instead of sending "source": "<svg xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\" Im sending "source": "<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" maybe this is the problem.

Comment: Since you're sending a JSON object, you might have more luck adding `'Content-Type': 'application/json'` to the headers.

Comment: Or you could try stringifying `body: JSON.stringify(bodyValue)` - as long as the server can understand it at the other end.